# How to Use Apple Push Notification on Mac?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, apple-push-notifications

I'm a newbie in OSX development.

I'm developing an app in mac which requires receiving notifications similar to the iOS APNS. I am fully aware of the Growl Framework, however many suggested that in order to avoid any future compatibility and/or support issue with Growl, using the Apple Push Notifications (applicable for Apps from Lion onwards) would be better.
Can you suggest a way on how to do this or give some important tutorial regarding this.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apples own documentation is the best place to start:

https://developer.apple.com/notifications/

Lots of documents there as well as videos from WWDC regarding mac notifications and sample code. In general the implementation is very similar to ios push.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Nikos. I have a follow-up question...since Apple only allows NC for Apps that are in the App Store, I'd like to know if how am I going to test if the Push Notification is working? Thanks!

Comment: If you are a registered developer you can set up test push notification to test before you submit to Apple. Dont worry.

Comment: I'm sorry if this may sound stupid, but is it the APN Tester App?

Comment: When you create the appropriate certificates via the Apple dev portal for setting up push notifications, you can create development or production certificates. With the development certificates you can test your app's push notifications before getting it to the App Store.

Comment: Thanks Nikos for the tip. :)

Comment: Hey Nikos, do you have any idea on how I can test the Push Notifications for OSx beta app? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain each set for OSX push notification. I have created a development certificate and what next need to be done (code to be implemented).

Comment: By the way, macOS push notifications are now supported outside the App Store.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/74662

Comment: @JayKoutavas I've got strictly opposite feeling from the provided link - push notifications requires provisioning profile, which is available only through stores.

Comment: As I understand it, provisioning is a base requirement for binary signing. Whereas a signed binary is a requirement for then optionally submission to a store.